# How to make Cmder PATH aware?

Tags: cmd, terminal, path

I recently installed a gorgeous terminal for Windows called Cmder. Everything works fine and it looks great.

But it becomes helpless when I run **node -v**: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have no idea why Cmder cannot find node as it runs in WebStorm Terminal, GitBash or even cmd.

Can anybody help?

Thank you!
Guenther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that Cmder had problems accepting the syntax of some weird MySQL path entries containing '&'. It simply stopped processing the remaining path string. After removing these path entries manually Cmder works fine and is "path aware".